# Prove that there exists a sequence of sets of finite measure in a $\sigma$-algebra that increases to the entire set.

Tags: measure-theory, semiring

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a semiring on a set $\Omega$. And let $\mu$ be a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ that is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{A}$. Prove that there exists a sequence of sets in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, with finite measure, that increases to $\Omega$.

This has been used to prove a part of the Approximation Theorem for Measures in Achim Klenke's book on Probability Theory.

The measure is $\sigma$-finite only on $\mathcal{A}$ but we are choosing sets of finite measure from $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, and this sequence increases to $\Omega$. I do not see how this can be possible. We can not choose the trivial example of the sequence being just $\{\Omega\}$ as $\Omega$ need not belong to an arbitrary semiring, further $\Omega$ may not have finite measure.

Comment: Have you tried to use the definition of $\sigma$-finite on a semiring?

Comment: @supinf Yup, so we have such a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$. Do we have such a sequence in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})\backslash\mathcal{A}$? To make it easier, how about a sequence in which not all elements are from $\mathcal{A}$? I know this last one is possible by taking any sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ that satisfies the condition and taking the union of each element with some set (of finite measure) that is in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})\backslash\mathcal{A}$, but is there any other way to get such a sequence generally?